# Subset SpatialLinesDataFrame based on @data info

Tags: r, gis, geo

I have a SpatialLinesDataFrame representing streets. I need to find the intersection of 2 streets.

I'll copy a toy example from  [How to get the intersection point of two vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21647982/how-to-get-the-intersection-point-of-two-vector)

```
library(rgdal)
library(rgeos)
a = c(1,5,2,6,3,6,3,5,7)
b = c(5,3,5,7,2,6,9,3,6)

SL1 <- SpatialLines(list(Lines(Line(cbind(seq_along(a),a)), "A")))
SL2 <- SpatialLines(list(Lines(Line(cbind(seq_along(b),b)), "B")))

# Build my own SpatialLines with both objects, couldn't find a way
# to build it from SL1 and SL2
SL <- SpatialLines(list(Lines(Line(cbind(seq_along(a),a)), "A"), Lines(Line(cbind(seq_along(b),b)), "B")))

SL.df <- SpatialLinesDataFrame(SL, data=data.frame(OBJECTID=paste(1:2), NAME=c("st 1", "av B"), row.names=row.names(SL)))
```

From the answer to the question I copied, I know I can get the intersection as

```
# Find intersections  
coords <- coordinates(gIntersection(SL1, SL2))
```

But suppose I have read SL.df with readOGR and don't have access to the original components. How should I extract individual streets?

After quite some wandering, I've come up with

```
st.1 <- SpatialLines(SL.df@lines[which(row.names(SL.df) == row.names(SL.df)[which(SL.df@data$NAME == 'st 1')])])
av.B <- SpatialLines(SL.df@lines[which(row.names(SL.df) == row.names(SL.df)[which(SL.df@data$NAME == 'av B')])])
coords <- coordinates(gIntersection(st.1, av.B))
```

It works, but the extraction of the individual streets doesn't seem very elegant. Is there a better way to do it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of options:

```
coordinates(gIntersection(subset(SL.df, NAME=="st 1"), 
                          subset(SL.df, NAME=="av B")))
#          x        y
# 1 1.666667 3.666667
# 1 2.400000 3.800000
# 1 4.500000 4.500000
# 1 6.000000 6.000000
# 1 7.750000 4.500000


coordinates(gIntersection(SL.df[SL.df$NAME=="st 1",], 
                          SL.df[SL.df$NAME=="av B",]))
#          x        y
# 1 1.666667 3.666667
# 1 2.400000 3.800000
# 1 4.500000 4.500000
# 1 6.000000 6.000000
# 1 7.750000 4.500000
```

Comment: Much better! Thank you.