# Find the number of pixel intersections along spatial lines

Tags: r, gis, r-sp

I have a raster with road pixels and a set of lines defined with the function *SpatialLines* (package *sp*). For each line, I would like to find the number of intersections with roads. My idea is, in a first time, to convert road pixels into objects of class *SpatialLines*, then to use the function *gIntersection* as in [How to get the intersection point of two vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21647982/how-to-get-the-intersection-point-of-two-vector).

Are there any functions to convert road pixels into objects of class *SpatialLines* or does anybody know a better way to find the number of road crossings along each line ?

I began to reclassify my raster to obtain only road pixels:

```
m <- c(1,0,2,0,3,0,4,0,5,0,6,0,7,0,8,0,9,0,10,1)
r <- matrix(m, ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
rc <- reclassify(data.raster, r)
```

Comment: Do the roads have unique ids?

Comment: No, the roads don't have unique ids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a couple of roads you can take with the raster package to get the number of crossings. For example:

```
library(raster)
# Example data
# lines
cds1 <- rbind(c(-180,-20), c(-140,55), c(10, 0), c(-140,-60))
cds2 <- rbind(c(-10,0), c(140,60), c(160,0), c(140,-55))
cds3 <- rbind(c(-125,0), c(0,60), c(40,5), c(15,-45))
lines <- spLines(cds1, cds2, cds3)

# raster
r <- raster(ncols=90, nrows=45)
values(r) <- sample(1:10, ncell(r), replace=TRUE)


roads <- subs(r, data.frame(from=10, to=1)) 
rline <- rasterize(lines, roads, field=1, fun='sum')

m <- mask(rline, roads)
cellStats(m, 'sum')
```

A different route:

```
e <- extract(r, lines)
s <- sapply(e, function(x) sum(x==10, na.rm=TRUE))
sum(s)
```

Perhaps this addresses Pierre's concern about double counting. Only non-adjacent crossings are counted:

```
e <- extract(r, lines)
s <- sapply(e, function(x) sum(diff(c(FALSE, x==10)) == 1, na.rm=TRUE))
sum(s)
```

adjacency could also be looked at via

```
e <- extract(r, lines, cellnumbers=TRUE)
```

and then using the adjacent function

Comment: But, if the width of a road corresponds to two pixels and the line crosses these two pixels, the code will consider the two pixels as two different intersections instead of one intersection !

Comment: @Pierre: thanks, excellent point. I have shown an approach to deal with that, I think. Although without further analysis, we cannot really know whether two adjacent road raster cells are representing the same road. It might be better to extract road lines after all.